# PyCharm "Unused import statement" when adding method to class

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, intellij-inspections

I want add a method to a class, without extending another class (for the import statements should be unaltered).

Conceptually, my current approach is:

`add_method.py`

```py
def new_method():
    pass

MyObject.new_method = new_method
```

`main.py`

```py
from package import MyObject
import add_method

ob = MyObject()
ob.new_method()
```

This does the job, however, PyCharm does not recognize that the `import add_method` import statement is acutally used: "Unused import statement". Is there an elegant way to obtain the same effect with PyCharm recognizing the import?

Comment: You dont' use `add_method` in your code, hence the `Unused import statement`. What else were you expecting?

Comment: Without importing `add_method`, MyObject will not have the `new_method`. Of course, there are other programming patterns to add the `new_method` to the MyObject class, however this one has the advantage of allowing extending existing objects without altering the class definition code.

Comment: It is very unexpected and in fact not reliable to have a package import have side effects like this. When doing `import foo`, you don't expect `foo` to impact another module `bar`, and you should use `foo` directly in some way in the module where it's imported. At least do some sort of decorator which you need to explicitly apply, like `foo.augment(MyObject)`.